# Beginner python: Formatting Lines

Tags: python, formatting, format

I was completing this code I had to write for an assignment but the issue is when I print out the code, it's not formatted correctly. I currently have the lines for a song within a list and when i print it out, the list includes brackets which is not what i want. I also want each line to have a new space and i tried using the '\n' line break to set it, but it also wont work. Attached is my code, any assistance with this formatting would be nice. Thanks!

def main():

```
    oldMac = []
    for stanza in range(3):
    animal = raw_input("What animal? ")
    animalSound = raw_input("What sound does a %s make? " %(animal))
    stanza1 = [
          "Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O,",
          "And on his farm he had a %s, E-I-E-I-O" %(animal),
          "With a %s-%s here - " %(animalSound, animalSound),
          "And a %s-%s there - " %(animalSound, animalSound),
          "Here a %s there a %s" %(animalSound, animalSound),
          "Everywhere a %s-%s" %(animalSound, animalSound),
          "Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O"]

    print stanza1

    for stanza in range(1):
        oldMac = oldMac + stanza1 

print "Here are the completed song lyrics: "
print
print oldMac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for stanza in stanza1:
        oldMac = oldMac + stanza + "\n"
```

you were adding stanzal which is a list

alternativly you could do

```
oldMac += "\n".join(stanza1)
```

and get rid of the for stanza

or probabbly the best solution

```
stanza = """Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O,
          And on his farm he had a {0}, E-I-E-I-O
          With a {1}-{1} here - 
          And a {1}-{1} there - 
          Here a {1} there a {1}
          Everywhere a {1}-{1}
          Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O""".format(animal, animalSound)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line

```
print stanza1
```

to

```
print '\n'.join(stanza1)
```

Outputs

```
What animal? cow
What sound does a cow make? moo

Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O,
And on his farm he had a cow, E-I-E-I-O
With a moo-moo here - 
And a moo-moo there - 
Here a moo there a moo
Everywhere a moo-moo
Old MacDonald had a farm, E-I-E-I-O
```